# How to use peerjs (import and require both fail)

Tags: javascript, import, require, peerjs

I want to use peerjs in a script (that I use in a html file).
When I try `import Peer from "peerjs"`, I get an error saying "Cannot use import statement outside a module".
When I try `var Peer = require("peerjs")`, I get an error saying simply "require is not defined".
Is there a way to use peerjs ? If yes, what is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use a library inside an HTML file you need to include its file in a script tag.
for example in your case, PeerJS documentation instructs to add this line:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.2/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
```

and then you can create a peer and connect.

take a look here: [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/)